# Orthonormal Basis and Hermitian inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal, change-of-basis

> We can choose different bases to define different inner products.
>   However, different orthonormal bases will generate the same inner
>   product.

Could anyone explain the last sentence? Why different orthonormal bases give the same inner product?

Comment: How is the inner product defined from the basis?

Comment: @JalexStark I think the idea is that you can write any vector as a linear combination of the basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, any basis defines the usual inner product in terms of coordinates, so that it actually becomes an orthonormal basis.

Now, if an inner product is given, and $b_1,\dots, b_n$ is an orthonormal basis, its inner product will coincide with the original one, because 
$$\left\langle\sum_i\alpha_ib_i,\, \sum_i\beta_ib_i\right\rangle\ =\ \sum_i\alpha_i\beta_i$$